# attr('selected','selected') not working in selectpicker bootsrap with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want to set the select option be selected when i get data with ajax, but it did not work. I need help. thank you

```js
function update(id) {
  $.ajax({
    url: "<?= site_url('masteruser/show/') ?>/" + id,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      $('select option[value=' + data.level + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select class="form-control" title="Pilih Level">
  <option value="Administrator">Administrator</option>
  <option value="Member">Member</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Use the `val()` method to set the selected option: `$('select').val(data.level)`. See the duplicate I marked for more information

Comment: Selecting an option does not render the `selected` attribute on the element in the DOM. The intention of that attribute is to pre-select a choice when the page is initially displayed.